# Prove the collection of all possible well-orderings of a set A is a set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a set. Prove that

$X=\{\text{tp}(A,R) \big | \hspace{1mm} R \hspace{2mm} \text{is a well-ordering on} \hspace{1mm} A\}$

is a set where $\text{tp}(A,R)$ is the ordinal which the well-ordered set $(A,R)$ is isomorphic to.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$

A relation, $R$, is a set of ordered-pairs from $A$. Therefore I want to construct a set of all ordered pairs from $A$. Then for each well-ordering, $R$, we have a distinct set of ordered pairs. For each set of ordered pairs find the ordinal which it is isomorphic to. Take the union of these and call it $X$.

Is this the correct way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt doesn't make much sense to me, and I can't understand your approach. We don't construct sets of pairs from $A$, often there are more well-orders of $A$ than pairs of elements of $A$, so we can't choose a unique pair for each $R$.

Instead, show that $\{R\subseteq A\times A\mid R\text{ is a well-ordering of }A\}$ is a set, then use the axiom of replacement to conclude that $X$ is a set.

Comment: I think this is exactly what the OP was trying to do when saying "Therefore I want to construct a set of all ordered pairs from A. Then for each well-ordering, R, we have a distinct set of ordered pairs." (The set of ordered pairs is $A×A$, and each well-ordering is a subset of it.)

Comment: @rewritten: Perhaps. But this method is doomed to begin with. There are far more ways to well-order $\Bbb N$ than there are pairs from $\Bbb N$.

Comment: I know that! :) The OP is identifying a well-ordering with a subset of $A×A$, therefore the missing step is "so a well-ordering is an element of the set $P(A×A)$" (and then using replacement as you say). But the rest of his reasoning is exactly the same as yours.

Comment: Perhaps it's just too early for me. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I assume this question is framed in $ZF$ set theory:

By the axioms of ZF, if $A$ is a set $A \times A$ is a set. By the power set axiom, $\mathcal{P}(A \times A)$ is a set. By the axiom of comprehension,

$WO(A) = \{W \in \mathcal{P}(A \times A) : W \text{ is a well-order }\}$

is a set. Hence the collection of well-ordering is a set.

Moreover $F(W) = tp(W)$ if $W$ is a well-ordering is a proper class function. By the axiom of replacement $F[WO(A)]$ is a set. This is what you called $X$ above.